# how to pass the json string from controller to view

Tags: java, spring, rest, model-view-controller

Hi I'm using Spring mvc project in that I have to pass the `json` String from controller to view the return code from controller is :

> return model.addObject("response", Response.getResults().toJSONString());

and the jsp code is :

```
    <%@ page language="java" content Type="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Response value</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            Response is : <c:out value="${response}" />
        </body>
    </html>`
```

I have run the call on postman and it successfully run and but cannot displayed the response string it only shows the jsp coding on postman.

can any one help me to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using Spring Rest Services @RestController plays an important Role.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/yourmapping")
public class yourController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public <returnType> getAll() {
    return <response>;
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response i was used this also but not working properly.Then I checked the version of the jsp then i add the <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> tag it will work fine.